# Geth Miner Will not Start

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a geth node for a private blockchain and the miner just does not start. I checked coinbase and defaultAccount and they look OK. Has anyone any ideas what could be the cause of this error?

```
> eth.mining
false
> miner.start(8)
null
> eth.mining
false
> 
> eth.coinbase
"0x5842d6acb3dca819471bde56255f27670aa9b9c6"
> eth.defaultAccount
"0x5842d6acb3dca819471bde56255f27670aa9b9c6"
> eth.getHashrate
function(callback)
> eth.getHashrate()
undefined
>
```

Here is the genesis.json file -

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 88888,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
},
"coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"difficulty" : "0x1",
"extraData" : "0x00",
"gasLimit" : "0x47e7c5",
"nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp" : "0x00",
"alloc" : {
    "c2d7cf95645d33006175b78989035c7c9061d3f9": {"balance": "888888888888888888888888"}
}
}

Here is the connection string - 

geth --datadir /geth/mybc --unlock "0x5842d6acb3dca819471bde56255f27670aa9b9c6"  --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport 8545 --networkid 1234 --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,shh,txpool,net,web3,personal"  console 2> console.log
```

Answer (score 1):

There was an old issue in geth, where it will not mine transactions when running private chain. The workaround was to start a second miner. Not sure if that issue was fixed or if its the same issue.

Comment: I have used the same geth and it works on another machine - unless I by accident installed an old geth version. I will check that.

Comment: I just restarted the geth client and now it is mining. Can geth have a timeout? I saw this before. It started and then just stopped and would not start again. Is there a limit somehow in geth?

Comment: This was the same issue I had. It was a syncing issue if I remember correctly. It's actually not an issue but happens for single miners

Comment: This was the issue if I am not mistaken. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2769#issuecomment-230249342 .Not fixed it seems

Comment: But that link is from mid-2016 when Ethereum was really embryonic. Now in 2018 I would expect basic elements such as mining to be resolved. I wonder if the issue is a parameter not setting somehow.

Comment: Seems this was not actually an issue. Which version geth are you using ?

Comment: instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72831/discussion-between-shon-js-and-trevor-oakley).

Comment: It mines now but balance is zero on all accounts. That sounds like some kind of coinbase issue, but coinbase is setup!

Comment: If it's mining blocks, then should be different issue. Need to look into it.